# find unique tags when the hierarchy has a specific child

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSL and finding it difficult to arrive at the expected results.
I have the below XML structure

My requirement is to fetch all the unique(through out the XML) `<Member>` tags of the `<RuleBndryValue1>` hierarchy when the associated `<Code> = Prod` from the `<result>` hierarchy only if the `<result>` has a child named `<Resource>`.

Sample XML:

```
<Envelope>
    <Header>      
   <ID>bdde10f67983</ID>
    </Header>
   <Body>
  <findResponse >
     <result >
        <Rule>                                   
           <RuleBoundary1>                                 
              <RuleBndryValue1>                     
                 <Member>CS</Member>
                 <Code>CSize</Code>                     
              </RuleBndryValue1>
           </RuleBoundary1>               
        </Rule>
        </result>                
     <result >
        <Rule>        

           <RuleBoundary1>                                 
              <RuleBndryValue1>                     
                 <Member>RL</Member>                     
                 <Code>A2</Code>                     
              </RuleBndryValue1>
           </RuleBoundary1>               
           <RuleBoundary1>                                  
              <RuleBndryValue1>                                        
                 <Member>Ad</Member>                     
                 <Code>Prod</Code>                     
              </RuleBndryValue1>
              <RuleBndryValue1>                                     
                 <Member>Customer</Member>                     
                 <Code>Prod</Code>                     
              </RuleBndryValue1>
           </RuleBoundary1>
        </Rule>
        <Resource>
           <ResourceId>39</ResourceId>              
        </Resource>
     </result>       

     <result>
        <Rule>
           <RuleId>1388</RuleId>                              
           <RuleBoundary1>   

              <RuleBndryValue1>                     
                 <Member>XXX</Member>                     
                 <Code>TP</Code>                     
              </RuleBndryValue1>
           </RuleBoundary1>
           <RuleBoundary1>                 
              <RuleBndryValue1>                     
                 <Member>Ad</Member>                    
                 <Code>Prod</Code>                     
              </RuleBndryValue1>
              <RuleBndryValue1>                    
                 <Member>Customer</Member>                     
                 <Code>Prod</Code>                     
              </RuleBndryValue1>
           </RuleBoundary1>
        </Rule>
        <Resource>
           <ResourceId>05</ResourceId>               
        </Resource>
     </result>         
  </findsResponse>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

The XML will have multiple instances of hierarchy `<result>`.My XSL code fetches all `<members>` , but I am not able to figure out how to restrict it to only those `<result>` hierarchies that have a `<Resource>`. So in the XML I've given the first occurrence of `<result>` does not meet the criteria.

XSL code:

```
<xsl:variable name="Prods">
    <xsl:for-each select="//findResponse/result/Rule/RuleBoundary1/RuleBndryValue1">
        <xsl:if test="Code = 'Prod'">
            <xsl:if test="Member[not(preceding::ns2:Member/. = .)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="Member[not(preceding::ns2:Member/. = .)]"/>
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Ad|Customer
```

Please let me know how I can restrict the above to desired Result hierarchy.

Comment: Your question is not readable. In general, unique values in XSLT 1.0 are obtained through the use of [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Alternatively, if your processor supports it you can use the EXSLT [set:distinct()](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html) extension function.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual output you expect for you current input? Thank you!

Comment: We can read your question. No need to repeat it in a comment. Better to spend your time adding a section to your question that shows the required output from your input. Highlight your new edit with your mouse then use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box to keep its format. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You  Tim C and  shellter, I have modified my question , hope it looks better now.

Comment: Can you please give some pointers how to go about this ?